# Configuration values for hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions and hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode in HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to add data to an external table using apache-hive. I am getting the following error in the hive logs

```
2015-06-15 17:27:44,614 ERROR [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0]: mr.ExecMapper (ExecMapper.java:map(171)) - org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"transactiondate":"05-01-2015 08:26:21","transactiontype":"CASHOUT","transactionid":144590889,"sourcenumber":null,"destnumber":null,"amount":19000,"assumedfield1":880,"customerid":33394093,"transactionstatus":"COMPLETED","assumedfield2":325,"assumedfield3":175870}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:518)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveFatalException: [Error 20004]: Fatal error occurred when node tried to create too many dynamic partitions. The maximum number of dynamic partitions is controlled by hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions and hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode. Maximum was set to: 256
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.getDynOutPaths(FileSinkOperator.java:933)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:837)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:837)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:162)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:508)
    ... 10 more
```

I googled for this error and came across [this link](http://documentation.altiscale.com/changing-hive-dynamic-partition-limits) which says that we must change the values of `hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions` and `hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode` variables to higher values. What are the optimum configurations for these variables on a single node hadoop installation? None of these configuration values are working for me. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=1000;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=250;
Please do not try to increase hive partitions to higher value .
It may cause Namenode crash . If possible try to change the partition column and apply new logic over it